# extracting tweets without oauth

Tags: ruby, twitter, oauth

I have tried various ruby codes to extract tweets, i came to know that in order to get tweets i have to create a twitter application and use Oauth for getting consumer key. My question here is can i not access the public tweets without using Oauth since i am working on a project where i have to analyze tweets. 
The ruby code that i tried is as follows

```
require 'tweetstream'
require 'rubygems'
TweetStream.configure do |config|
config.username = 'twitterusername'
config.password = 'twitterpassword'
config.auth_method = :basic
end
@client = TweetStream::Client.new
@client.sample do |status|
puts "#{status.text}"
end
```

I get Failed to reconnect to twitter error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no access to the twitter api with out Oauth.  You will need to create a twitter application in order to request this information from the API.

You can start reading here:  [Authentication & Authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth)